# Fill div with position absolute - auto width

Tags: css

Im trying to make a div fill out the correct amount, corresponding to the text within it. This is normal behaviour with divs, but when adding position:relative and absolute theres trouble.

```
<div style="position:relative;background-color:#CDCDCD;">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;">sadasd</div>
</div>
```

Its simple, i just want the background color to fill as long as the text goes. Setting a width is not an option.

I've tried with width:auto and display:block but I cant get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;background-color:#CDCDCD;">sadasd</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the background-color to the inner div, that will do the job!